# AngularJS Directive not being applied

Tags: angularjs, datetimepicker, directive

I am using a plugin (jackrabbits-angularjs-datetimepicker) and it works fine using their example.

However, I want to hide/show the form based on another input. I've noticed if I hide/show the directive based on an input it seems that the directive never gets applied (I am left with just an input field).

For example if they want training - I will show/hide a form to allow them to input date/time (show/hide being done with ng-show).

Is there a way to fire off applying the directive again? Is the directive applied during page load - thus causing the show/hide not to apply directive?

Comment: You have to provide some code so people can help you

Answer (score 0):

If you use ng-if instead of ng-show, the directive will be reapplied again.
You can make your directive to actually listen/wait on an attribute/scope prop and reapply itself again instead of relying on ng-if, but in order to give you more information, we'd have to see some code.

If ng-if is fine for you, you should know that it re-renders everything that is inside every time when the condition is changed. Ng-show, on the other hand, just applies a hidden style to the element and its children so your directive wouldn't be "applied" twice.

Ng-if also creates an isolate scope (one scope deeper than the scope on which it is placed) which might or might not be a concern to you.

Comment: Changing my ng-show to ng-if still same issue - I have included the HTML and JS here - http://jsfiddle.net/5b06abhj/

Answer (score 0):

I tested the library and saw your issue, it appears that the directive breaks when using some ng properties.

I was able to make it work if I used ng-if/show/hide on a surrounding element. Eg wrap the directive in a div.

**Update**:
Find a Codepen here: http://codepen.io/tobiasc/pen/XbNZLz

Note the difference in ng-if & ng-show. ng-if pulls the elements out of the DOM, while ng-show only sets "display: none;". This implies that if you show/hide a element with ng-if, it's reset. While if you show/hide an element with ng-show it maintains state, in this case it'll retain whatever selection the user made.

HTML:

```
<body ng-app="datetimepickerDemo">
    <div ng-controller="tmpCtrl">
        <div ng-if="showTime">
            <datetimepicker data-ng-model="data.embeddedDate" data-datetimepicker-config="{ startView:'day', minView:'day' }" />
        </div>
        <button ng-click="showTimeChange(true)">Enable</button>
        <button ng-click="showTimeChange(false)">Disable</button>
    </div>
</body>
```

JS:

```
angular.module('datetimepickerDemo').controller('tmpCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.showTime = true;
    $scope.showTimeChange = function (bool) {
        $scope.showTime = bool;
    };
});
```

Comment: That looks like the same type of structure I have laid out in my html - I have include the html and a portion of the controller. http://jsfiddle.net/5b06abhj/

Comment: I've created a small codepen to show case the above example with the correct library: http://codepen.io/tobiasc/pen/XbNZLz